# Though I follow _Block , Memory Leak Happening @ ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Its my code , can you help where am I missing to handle Memory? I'm using X-Code 4.6. And also I have checked instrument , to get other memory leaks. Its almost showing all "ASIHTTPRequest". Im not handling manually like [request release]; Is that necessary to fix memory leak? Thanks in advance

```
       __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
                       }];
        [request setFailedBlock:^{

        }];
        [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
        [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: are you using ARC ?? and why the __block identifier ?? I dont see you using the `request` variable inside the block ??

Comment: NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

Im using it. Yes im using ARC.

Comment: im following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736145/instrument-xcode4-report-asihttprequest-leak-memory. Help me what exactly going wrong? Im getting leaks in Mutable Array also :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It leaks because of the retain cycle created between the block and the request object.

Try the below:

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *weakRequest = request;
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
                   }];
[request setFailedBlock:^{

}];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Cheers..

**EDIT:**

ASIHTTPRequest is [not supported](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;) anymore, try to move to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/), it is the best.

Comment: May be obvious to some, but you might want to point out that within each block, you should use use `weakRequest`, and not `request`.

Comment: +1 Wow ! Super Its Fixed :) I used "weakRequest" in all request places. Thanks Tarek

Comment: Pro tip: you can use `__typeof()` like this: `__weak __typeof(request) weakRequest = request;` instead of duplicating the type name all over the place. Works with `self` as well of course.

Comment: Learning from open source library is a good way.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/d492c4bff5eb0f532f95d015b4aafec6fd735edf/AFNetworking/AFURLConnectionOperation.m#L320

Answer (score 0):

Then instead do this:

```
    __weak __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        __strong ASIHTTPRequest *requestInBlock = request;
        //your code, and replace all refrences of request inside the block with requestInBlock.
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        //same here
    }];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60];
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

try this out.

Comment: This may fail in release code (with optimization) since after the first statement there might be no strong reference to the request object. @Tarek's technique of having a local strong reference and a separate weak reference will survive optimization.